# Reshaping MultiIndex to separate

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

After reading the documentation of pandas and MultiIndex, many posts here, I still don't fully grasp the concept. Could some one help me finding this one line of code.

I want to create a boxplot from data from a xls file. The clue would be to show two boxplots, one for parameter=33 and one where parameter=77. So my dataset needs to have the results split by the parameter. Any attempts with unstacking somehow failed as I don't fully get the concept

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas
import numpy as np
wbName= "Test (1).xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"
sort_by=['Name','Parameter']
df = pandas.read_excel(open(wbName, "rb"), sheetname=wsName)
id_col=list()
for sb in sort_by:
    id_col.append(np.where(df.columns.values==sb)[0][0])
df = pandas.read_excel(open(wbName, "rb"), sheetname=wsName, index_col=id_col)
print(df)
#oneline magic needed
df.plot.box()
```

So the print(df) returns (as expected)

```
Name Parameter        
sdf  33             99
     33             99
     33             99
     33            645
     33            345
     77            567
     77             45
     77            456
     77            456
     77            234
     77            576
     77             45
ere  33             99
     33             99
     33             99
     33            645
     33            345
     77            567
     77             45
     77            456
     77            456
     77            234
     77            576
     77             45
```

but I assume that I just need one line to contert in into (number not macthing above exaple)

```
Result             
Parameter        33   77
Name         
sdf               99   567
                  99   45
                  99   456
                 645   456
                 345   456 
ere               99   546 
                  99  465
                  99  456 
                 645  46
```

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `pd.MultiIndex` is not unique.

assume your series is `s`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({n: g.reset_index(drop=True) for n, g in s.groupby(level=[0, 1])})
df.stack(0).reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index()
```

[image]

---

## ***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """Name Parameter   Value    
sdf  33             99
sdf  33             99
sdf  33             99
sdf  33            645
sdf  33            345
sdf  77            567
sdf  77             45
sdf  77            456
sdf  77            456
sdf  77            234
sdf  77            576
sdf  77             45
ere  33             99
ere  33             99
ere  33             99
ere  33            645
ere  33            345
ere  77            567
ere  77             45
ere  77            456
ere  77            456
ere  77            234
ere  77            576
ere  77             45"""

s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=[0, 1], squeeze=True)
```